# Xterm doesn't load with .xdefaults when launched from Cinnamon startup menu in Fedora 25

Tags: fedora, configuration, xterm

Xterm and the .xdefaults file were not pre-loaded on my system in the first place and even after running Xterm once, I had to create .xdefaults myself. I believe I've put it in the right place:

/home/(user)

For what reason is Xterm ignoring my .xdefaults file? It looks like this now:

```
xterm*dynamicColors::     true
xterm*background::        black
xterm*foreground::        white
xterm*utf8::              2
xterm*eightBitInput::     true
xterm*saveLines::         32767
xterm*scrollTtyKeypress:: true
xterm*scrollTtyOutput::   false
xterm*scrollBar::         false
xterm*loginShell::        true
xterm*faceName::          Monospace:pixelsize=11
xterm*jumpScroll::        true
xterm*multiScroll::       true
xterm*toolBar::           false
xterm*geometry::          100x30
```

Is this correct?

Answer (score 0):

Two colons (**`::`**) isn't correct syntax.

Also, you'll get better results using the class name **`XTerm`** than the instance name **`xterm`**.

Also, ".xdefaults" isn't right (that's a leading "X" rather than "x", and most configurations insist that you suffix the filename with the hostname, e.g., ".Xdefaults-myhostname").

You didn't mention xrdb - that's commonly suggested as a convenient hammer (aka "solution").  But if you're using ".Xdefaults-whatever", xrdb is largely irrelevant.

To see what's visible in the X resources, I'd install "appres", and do

```
appres XTerm
```

Comment: OK, did that, but XTerm still isn't remembering my settings from last use. How do I make that happen?

Comment: Wow great, `.Xdefaults-hostname` did the trick for me on Fedora 30, had been looking some time for a working solution.